# Using 1 script to assign different values based on tags - C# - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a Game on Unity 3D. I have 1 script which i am using on 2 different characters(prefabs)

So I have this variable called Target

```
public Transform Target;
```

This script is passed on Hero and vilain both. I want script to get Hero as target for villain and villain as target for hero. Maybe I can do it with tags??

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this just drag&drop of your target transform onto the variable "Target" in your script in the property window?

Comment: Yes if i set it public i can drag and drop but lets say i have 5 different characters for heros and 5 for villains. Now i want that i call a hero randomly and a villain randomly [This much i have done successfully], all i want is that all villains have tag of enemy and heroes have tags of player and automatically select the visible prefab of opposite.

Comment: Would something like this work? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html

Comment: Hi, I have looked into this Page but this isn't helping.

These are the two ways i have tried but after both the codes, same value gets assigned to both prefabs of different tags.

     GameObject PlayerTargets = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        PlayerTargets = FKManage.Enemy;
        Target = PlayerTargets.transform;
2

if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player"))
        {
this.Target = FKManage.Enemy.transform;
}
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy"))
        {
this.Target = FKManage.LocalPlayer.transform
}

Comment: What i am trying to do is, logic i want is 

FOR ALL THE GAMEOBJECTS WITH TAG PLAYERS SET TARGET = ENEMY

FOR ALL THE GAMEOBJECTS WITH TAG ENEMEY SET TARGET = PLAYER

Using 1 c# script

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
if(Target.tag == "Hero"){
//hero Detected
}
```

or

```
if(Target.tag == "Villan"){
//Villan Detected
}
```

Suppose you have a script, attached to both (Hero and Villan)

```
 class xyz: MonoBehaviour{
    public Transform Target;
    void Start(){
         if(this.tag == "Villan"){
              //Villan Detected, assign hero
         }
         else if(this.tag == "Hero"){
             //Hero Detected, assign Villan
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your support.

I tried it but unfortunately script checks the tags of villain and change the value of target for both, then it goes down and change the value again for both. However, i found another way around which i am uploading in "Answer your question" for everyone to see.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution, pretty simple but took me a whole day to figure out lol.

```
GameObject[] protagonistOpponent = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        foreach (GameObject obst in protagonistOpponent)
            obst.GetComponent<User_Stats>().Target = FKManage.Enemy.transform;

        GameObject[] AntagonistOpponent = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
        foreach (GameObject obst in AntagonistOpponent)
            obst.GetComponent<User_Stats>().Target = FKManage.LocalPlayer.transform;
```

Thank you all who tried helping me :)